# How to make a transparent nav bar on the background image which has overlay?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm beginner and i'm trying to do this for my practice. [Please check this](http://foundry.mediumra.re/chooser.html)

Can any one help me to do the nav bar section and the overlay section ?

On scroll the nav bar colour changes from section 1 and it doesn't show up on overlay when we scroll

Comment: You can consider two layer..where navbar section will be above the overlay section..use CSS position and zindex props to achieve this..fo making it fixed you have to handle it through a scroll event and add a class when its fixed and for that class add a background color white...can you try this approach ?

Comment: @AravindS can you please make it in a snippet so I can learn and understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the codepen for the explanation I made in the comment section

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/NzbdwK)

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
        document.getElementById("nav").className = "fixed";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nav").className = "";
    }
})
```

```css
header{
  background:url("http://foundry.mediumra.re/img/home2.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
#nav{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:40px;
  background:none;
}
#nav.fixed{
  background:#fff;
  position:fixed;
  color:#000;
  
}
.content{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  margin:30px 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>
    <div id="nav">
      Navigation
    </div>  
  </header>
    <section>
      <div class="content">Test Content</div>
      <div class="content">Test Content</div>
      <div class="content">Test Content</div>
      <div class="content">Test Content</div>
      <div class="content">Test Content</div>
      <div class="content">Test Content</div>
      <div class="content">Test Content</div>
      <div class="content">Test Content</div>       <div class="content">Test Content</div>
      <div class="content">Test Content</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

This is using pure JS and CSS. Let me know this is what you are looking for.
Thanks!

Comment: Thankyou. It helped me

Comment: But how to add overlay and text on it?

Comment: @ravanone  I believe its background image is giving the feel of the overlay. let me know where you wan the overlay in detail. Thanks!